# getInitialProps is not returning API's response

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I got this code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

import Layout from '../../src/components/layout'
import Nav from '../../src/components/nav'
import Fluid from '../../src/components/fluid'

Post.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://schoolvol.mdcholewka.now.sh/api/getPost?slug=${query.slug}`)
  const json = await res.json()
  return json
}

function Post({ post }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Nav />
      <Fluid>
        {post ? <p>{post.id}</p> : <p>Ładowanie...</p>}
      </Fluid>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Post
```

The problem is, when I load the site it returns "Ładowanie..." (which means loading in Polish). After a while, nobody happens. What's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at this sample: https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/fetching-data-for-pages/fetching-batman-shows. Instead of doing `return json`, I believe that you have to use `return { post: json }`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just remove these `{}` out of function's arguments and it's now working fine.